# How to use Jasmine/Javascript for anonymous functions

Tags: jasmine, anonymous-function

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to go inside anonymous functions in jasmine.

Sample of method:

```
numerateColumns: function (rows) {
            rows.each(function () {
                var $row = $(this);
                $row.children().each(function (index) {
                    var $cell = $(this);
                    $cell.addClass('column-' + (index + 1));
                });
            });
        }
```

Try to test with:

```
 it("[TEST] Should call each method.", function () {

            // setup
            var rows = {
                each: function () {
                    return {
                        children: function () {
                            return {
                                replaceWith: function () {
                                    return null;
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            spyOn(rows, 'each').and.callThrough();

                // method under test
                module.numerateColumns(rows);

                // expectations
                expect(rows.each).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
```

But coverage test shows me that code of method is read only in first line (rows.each).

How to force it to read all the code inside (function() {}) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to test jQuery? It works perfectly, if not - some tests probably it will catch before new version publication.

```js
function numerateColumns($rows) {
  $rows.each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    $row.children().each(function(index) {
      var $cell = $(this);
      $cell.addClass('column-' + (index + 1));
    });
  });
}

describe('Iterate over columns`', function() {
  var mockRows

  beforeEach(function() {
    mockRows = $('<div><div></div></div>')
  })

  it("calls .each() on passed jQuery collection", function() {
    spyOn($, 'each').and.callThrough();
    
    expect($.each).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    numerateColumns(mockRows);

    expect($.each).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("adds CSS class to each child", function() {
    var column = $(mockRows[0]).find('div');
    
    expect(column.hasClass('column-1')).toBeFalsy()
    
    numerateColumns(mockRows);

    expect(column.hasClass('column-1')).toBeTruthy()

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
```

What you can test - it is extracted business logic that is independent to jQuery itself.